# Make boxes wider in django

Tags: html, css, django

I am currently doing a website and i'm using django all-auth for all the authentication.

Anyways, It all works perfectly, but I'd like to know if there's any way to make the username and password boxes bigger using html. Here's the code I've used:

```
<div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                        <div class="col-lg-40">
                            {{ form | crispy }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the image of the template in case you need a reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a good answer without having more context, such as which CSS framework you're using.  But based on what I think you are asking, no, it would not be ideal to use html to modify the width.  I would use CSS.  I would find wherever `col-lg-40` is specified and see if it is limiting your width.  If so, and you want to change that width for all instances of the `col-lg-40`, then you can change it.  A better idea is to use a different CSS class that does what you want, either provided by your CSS framework or custom made by you.

You can dual-class CSS classes on an element so you could provide a class that overrides the width declarations in `col-lg-40` if you really wanted to.